# Evenote using Wine does not work on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wine, 15.10, evernote

I am trying to run Evernote using Wine, but it seems it is not working properly. Although the program launches, I am getting the same GUI where it is not possible to edit my notes:

[image: Evernote screenshot]

The problem is that nothing appears where I should be able to edit the note. I hope I can solve this problem because I really need Evernote working on Ubuntu.

Comment: Choose a 32 bit wine arch, and see if that solves it.

Comment: Which version of Wine do you have and which version of Evernote do you want to install?

Comment: As an alternative you could use [Everpad](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/use-evernote-in-ubuntu-with-everpad). It's old and seems a little abandoned but according to others it still works.

Comment: I have no plans of using Everpad dude!

Answer (score 1):

According to the WineHQ database, Internet Explorer 8 may need to be installed through winetricks before the official Evernote application will work properly under Linux: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33338

There is more information about downloading and using winetricks here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks , or you can just use [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) (available through the official Ubuntu repositories), which bundles Wine and Winetricks with a nice GUI interface.

Other possible options for a Linux Evernote client include the open-source third-party applications [NeverNote](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/) and [NixNote](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nevernote/files/).

Comment: I have installed Internet Explorer 8, but it does work yet. I am having the same interface where I am not able to edit my notes.

Comment: I'm reading that other people are having trouble editing notes with the latest versions of the official evernote client. If you're willing to try a slightly outdated version, here's a link to download Evernote version 5.8 (latest is 5.9): [link](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/86114-new-evernote-for-windows-5813-ga-update/). I got it from the detailed discussion of EverNote under WINE here: [link](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/66262-running-evernote-using-wine-on-linux/)

Comment: Otherwise, your choices seem to be between the web interface, a third-party client that works in Linux (like NixNote or NeverNote), or one of Evernote's more linux-friendly competitors. NixNote does have a recent 2.0 beta version that is packaged as a .deb file, though I haven't tried it myself.